# Insert rows into a table where a row doesn't exist already using a Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I was tasked with inserting 1400 rows into a database table, only if the row doesn't already exists.

Best practice or not, I'm using a Cursor but looking for suggestions on best way to do this. Here's what I'm doing...

I have a table with data

```
Declare @Table TABLE (cd Varchar(10), IsActive Varchar(1), IsValid Varchar(1))

Insert into @Table (cd, IsActive, IsValid )

Select 'X1', 'Y', 'N'
Select 'T1', 'N', 'N'


Declare @Cd Varchar(10)
Declare @IsActive  Varchar(1)
Declare @IsValid  Varchar(1)


declare db_cursor CURSOR

    FOR SELECT Cd, IsActive, IsValid from @Table

    OPEN db_cursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor  into @Cd, @IsActive , @IsValid 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN --IsActive
           
           --this table: dbo.t_Tbl below will either have a row like this or not

           --Cd      ColName    ValString
           --X1      IsActive   'Y'
           
           IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from dbo.t_Tbl where cd = @Cd and column = 'IsActive')
           BEGIN
                Insert into dbo.t_tbl (Cd, ColName, ValString)
                Values (@Cd, 'IsActive', @IsActive)
           END

           
           /*********************************************/
           --Of course I'd like to apply the same logic to IsValid
           --Check if row doesn't exist
           --Then insert



        END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

For one, I'm not sure why, but this Cursor is looping through way more data than anticipated. There's only 1 row that I'm testing with.

But also, am I going overboard with using a cursor to accomplish this.

Comment: A `CURSOR` is by far the *worst* practice here; do you "have" to use one?

Comment: @Larnu - not at all. Well good to know!

Comment: Where's your subsequent FETCH NEXT inside the loop?!?!

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I guess that's where the issue is :)

Comment: What's the reason this can't be accomplished with a set based approach? If you don't have an answer, or the answer is "I'm not sure how", then you probably don't need a cursor.

Comment: @SOS - no reason at all I guess. First thought was Cursor

Comment: Try a subquery and not exists to start with and go from there. Conceptutally  something like: INSERT INTO destTbl SELECT cols, ... FROM sourceTbl WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT Cols FROM destTbl WHERE destTbl.cd = sourceTble.cd AND ... )